# Is there a C library for WEP, WPA, and WPA2

Tags: c, wep, wpa

Is there a library much like how openssl is imported into C programs that would allow easy access to WEP, WPA, and WPA2 functions?

I have never programmed in C and a friend is asking.

Comment: You can also use wpa_cli for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Open1X](http://open1x.sourceforge.net/) is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's [wpa_supplicant](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/) which probably fits your needs. It's a program, not a library, but it should be possible to modify it to be used as a library if necessary. However, wpa_supplicant doesn't support all OSes and chipsets as wifi encryption is (in contrast to SSL/TLS) very dependant on the underlying hardware.